# How to use amcharts in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, charts, amcharts

I have to use am charts(Column type) in asp.net but I dont knw how to use it. I have read some articles but none of them have proper guidelines to use it. Can anyone provide code example of am charts. I need example for both .aspx page and .aspx.cs page. Moreover I want to add effect in my graph. The effect should be like the column at x axis should slowly increase up to certain value at y-axis.
Which are the files that I need to include in .aspx page and in my project?

Comment: What you have to do here is to render the javascript data that amcharts needs via asp.net - the two of them are not connected.

Comment: @Aristos Can you please show it with example...?